# What is actual difference between Apache Tajo and Apache hive

Tags: apache, hadoop, hive, apache-tajo, bigdata

Recently there's being development going on for the **Apache Tajo project**. The project has an objective of being **"advanced open source data warehouse system in Hadoop for processing web-scale data sets"**.

Since we already have Apache hive as a data warehouse for hadoop and is now advanced and widely used across, How useful and different would this new project be for the hadoop world?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have your warehouse stable on Hive, I'm pretty sure you don't have to move away in the short term. Couple of areas that Tajo is trying to access are:

1. Low latency queries (ad-hoc): you might be getting fast-enough results using Impala/ Tez and hive-on-spark is coming with CDH 5.7. For even faster response, a different DB (not usually DWH) can be used.
2. Full SQL Support: As long as people who are using hive are already comfortable with HQL, there's no pressing need for SQL. Although you can easily understand why it's a benefit to have full-sql support.